# How to pass data from 3rd Activity to 1st activity

Tags: android

There are 3 activities :

1. Main Activity (Contains 3 fragments : a. Profile Fragment , b. Order Fragment, Item Fragment)
2. Order Summary Activity
3. Payment Screen

I wanted to pass order id from payment screen to Main Activity(Order fragment).

The flow : Main Activity(Profile Fragment) -> Main Activity(Item Fragment) -> Order Summary Activity -> Payment Screen -> Main Activity(Order Fragment)

Answer (score 0):

First, please use single activity architecture it's recommended. But to solve your problem you can simply use `registerForActivityResult` to communicate between activities. for example, if you want to move from MainActivity to OrderSummaryActivity you can use the below code inside MainActivity to get result from OrderSummaryActivity

```
fun openNextActivityForResult() {
    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, OrderSummaryActivity::class.java)
    resultLauncher.launch(intent)
}

var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val data: Intent? = result.data
        doSomeOperations()
    }
}
```

In your OrderSummaryActivity write below code to return data to MainActivity

```
var data = Intent()
data.putExtra("key","my data")
setResult(RESULT_OK,data)
finish()
```

And the same way for communication between OrderSummaryActivity and PaymentScreenActivity.